# Jmeter http path value finder using beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Consider we have a URL path as below,
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=${query_string)
where query_string is a variable passed from a csv file.

Now in Jmeter bean shell pre/post processor i need the original URL before assigning the variable value, ie, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=${query_string).

Do we have any way to retrieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using Beanshell as it has known performance problems so consider switching to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language.

The relevant groovy code you can use in [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) or [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) would be something like:

```
def url = sampler.getUrl();

def protocol = url.getProtocol()
def host = url.getHost()
def path = url.getPath()

log.info('Full URL: ' + url.toString())

log.info('URL you want: ' + protocol + '://' + host + path)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Get URL]

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details about Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. But this will again gives the current path. I actually want the path before replacing the jmeter variables.

Answer (score 0):

Save your url in a variable myUrl

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=${query_string}

When you use the url execute [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function

```
 ${__V(myUrl)}
```

This will return https://www.google.co.in/search?q=myString

When you need the original URL use

```
 ${myUrl}
```